# this.http.post(...).map is not a function

Tags: http, angular

```
doSelectMessagesAttributesUrl1(pushRequest : PushRequest) {
    console.info("sending post request");

    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

    return this.http
        .post(this.selectMessagesAttributesUrl, {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json().data)
        .subscribe(
            data => { },
            err => { console.error('An error occurred', err) }
        );
}
```

I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.http.post(...).map is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:937
zone.js:461 

Unhandled Promise rejection: this.http.post(...).map is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: this.http.post(...).map is not a function(…)
```

what is missing in my http syntax?

Answer (score 4):

You need to import rxjs like

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: i have this already, and yet i see this error

Comment: Be aware this usage of import will drastically increase bundle size

Comment: // -----------------  map -----------------------
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';